# Restart Vue transition

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have defined a transition group in Vue

```
<transition-group
        name="staggered-scale"
        tag="div"
        :css="false"
        @before-enter="animationBeforeEnter"
        @enter="animationEnter"
        appear>
    <span v-for="i in range" :key="i" :data-index="i">{{ i }}</span>
</transition-group>
```

I have some Javascript hooks that control the animation.

```
animationBeforeEnter(el) {
  el.style.transform = 'scale(0.1)';
}

animationEnter(el, done) {
  const delay = el.dataset.index * 30;
  setTimeout(() => {
    el.style.transform = 'scale(1.0)';
    done();
  }, delay);
}
```

When the component is initially rendered, the animation plays just fine. However, can I programmatically trigger the animation to run again?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can bind a parameter to a special attribute [`:key`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#key) for a `transition-group` and each time parameter's value changes it will causes re-render and animation will runs again.

Define a parameter:

```
data(){
    return {
        animationTrigger : false
    }
}
```

Markup:

```
<transition-group
        name="staggered-scale"
        tag="div"
        :key="animationTrigger"
        :css="false"
        @before-enter="animationBeforeEnter"
        @enter="animationEnter"
        appear>

    <span 
        v-for="i in range" 
        :key="i"
        :data-index="i">
        {{ i }}
    </span>

</transition-group>
```

And then run animation by changing `animationTrigger` value like this:

```
animationTrigger = !animationTrigger
```

---

Found [there](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/how-do-i-run-a-transition-on-an-element-again-when-it-hasnt-changed/4064/3), but also this use-case mentioned in the documentation by the link above.

And here is [my example](https://jsfiddle.net/panamaprophet/z77bdd8u/).